# How to make a horizontal style metro app With grids that are full size?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

[image]

How would you go about making a scrollviewer contain two grids that are screen sized?

One thing I thought up was to have the Grid size set to the screen size programmically, but I would imagine MS having a better solution.

The grouping I came up with:

```
<SematicZoom.ZoomedIn>
  <ScrollViewer //Horizontal>
    <StackPanel //Orientation is Horizontal>
       <Grid Height = "{Binding ScreenHeight}" Width = "{Binding ScreenWidth}">
          //Content
       </Grid>
       <Grid Height = "{Binding ScreenHeight}" Width = "{Binding ScreenWidth}">
          //Content
       </Grid>

    </StackPanel>
  </ScrollViewer>
</SematicZoom.ZoomedIn>
```

Comment: Just fyi... that kind od screen layout is generally frowned upon.  Guidelines say that if you have content that exists off screen, some of that content should straddle the edge to give the user a visual cue that more of the UI is available off screen.  Obviously, if you app depends on that behavior then do what you need to do.

Comment: @JeffBrand-MSFT Wow I never realized that when I was using Metro apps! For sure I will add some sort of visual cue now, since I can spread my content out more.